# Gradle offline build does not work with Mac 10.9.3

Tags: gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I want to use my android studio 6.0 without internet connection, to do this, I set this options:

> Preferences > Gradle > Offline work

but I am still get the message:

> Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing,
>   debugging) will not work properly

When I try to compile, I get the Error:

> Error running app: Gradle project sync failed. Please fix your project
>   and try again.

Could anyone help me or got the same problem?

Thank you

Comment: Same thing happened to me too. If I am offline, I can't build using Gradle :(

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know what the exact problem is, I can suggest a workaround.

Change `build.gradle` to start with that:

```groovy
buildscript {
    repositories {
        if ('allow' == System.properties['build.network_access']) {
            mavenCentral()
        } else {
            maven {
                url 'dependencies'
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.0-beta2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

So, when `build.network_access=allow` gradle system property is defined, online `mavenCentral()` repository will be used. Otherwise, build will use local offline maven repository inside `dependencies` folder.

The trick now is to generate that local offline maven repository. For that I use this script (`fetch_dependencies.py`):

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os
import subprocess
import glob
import shutil

# Place this in build.gradle:
# repositories {
#     if ('allow' == System.properties['build.network_access']) {
#         mavenCentral()
#     } else {
#         maven { url 'dependencies' }
#     }
# }
def main(argv):
    project_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    repo_dir = os.path.join(project_dir, "dependencies")
    temp_home = os.path.join(project_dir, ".gradle_home")
    if not os.path.isdir(temp_home):
        os.makedirs(temp_home)
    subprocess.call(["gradle", "-g", temp_home, "-Dbuild.network_access=allow"])
    cache_files = os.path.join(temp_home, "caches/modules-*/files-*")
    for cache_dir in glob.glob(cache_files):
        for cache_group_id in os.listdir(cache_dir):
            cache_group_dir = os.path.join(cache_dir, cache_group_id)
            repo_group_dir = os.path.join(repo_dir, cache_group_id.replace('.', '/'))
            for cache_artifact_id in os.listdir(cache_group_dir):
                cache_artifact_dir = os.path.join(cache_group_dir, cache_artifact_id)
                repo_artifact_dir = os.path.join(repo_group_dir, cache_artifact_id)
                for cache_version_id in os.listdir(cache_artifact_dir):
                    cache_version_dir = os.path.join(cache_artifact_dir, cache_version_id)
                    repo_version_dir = os.path.join(repo_artifact_dir, cache_version_id)
                    if not os.path.isdir(repo_version_dir):
                        os.makedirs(repo_version_dir)
                    cache_items = os.path.join(cache_version_dir, "*/*")
                    for cache_item in glob.glob(cache_items):
                        cache_item_name = os.path.basename(cache_item)
                        repo_item_path = os.path.join(repo_version_dir, cache_item_name)
                        print "%s:%s:%s (%s)" % (cache_group_id, cache_artifact_id, cache_version_id, cache_item_name)
                        shutil.copyfile(cache_item, repo_item_path)
    shutil.rmtree(temp_home)
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

It will run the build in online mode to download all dependencies. After that, it will copy jars and poms into `dependencies` folder creating a local maven repository there. You can even push this `dependencies` folder into the source control.

After that you can build offline either with `gradle --offline build` (or just `gradle build`) or with Android Studio.